# How to get Java perspective on custom Eclipse product

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I created a simple eclipse plugin that just opens a new view from a command in the menu. I am using Eclipse RCP 2018 and when I run the plugin as an application everything looks exactly the same as the java perspective with the menu option added (which is what I want).

When I create a product and run, it looks like a lot of options are gone (e.g no java perspective, can't make a java project, no source option, no refactor, no run, can't change it to dark theme, etc). My custom view/menu is still there but I want it to basically be an addition to what was already there like when I launch it as an application. Is there certain settings or files I can edit to accomplish this?

Comment: What do mean by 'create a product and run'? What exactly are you doing?

Comment: What I did was file -> new -> other -> Plugin development -> product configuration. Then I pressed next and selected the option "use a launch configuration" and selected the application configuration I used to run it originally. This created a .product file,  I double clicked this file and added the necessary plugins for it. I then went to the overview tab of the .product file and there is a testing section which, if clicked on, tests the product by launching an instance of it.

Comment: If you used an existing, working, launch configuration why did you have to edit the plugins? You will need all the plugins that were in the launch configuration.

Comment: Correct but in the .product file under the content tab, it doesn't automatically copy the required plugins, so I had to press the "add required plugins" in that tab and that adds the same plugins that existed in the launch configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you do not need your own product definition but just want to add your plugins to Eclipse IDE product. In that case you need to select "org.eclipse.sdk.ide" product to run and ensure your plugins are selected in launch configuration.

If you do need your own product definition for some reason (to show your own branding for example) and still need some functionality from Eclipse IDE - you need to add either features (preferable) or bundles to your product definition.

More details [here](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseProductDeployment/article.html)

Comment: Gotcha thanks, it looks like I wanted to make a feature product rather than a plugin product to get all the other functionalities I wanted.